# Unable to run Hubstaff

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, kde5

I am using Kubuntu 18.04 and I can't launch Hubstaff.

First I downloaded it from [here](https://app.hubstaff.com/download)

Second, `./Hubstaff-1.4.4-556fe980.sh` to install it. I just followed the steps. And here are all the messages that showed in the terminal.

```
astro@Wajih-HP:~/Téléchargements$ ./Hubstaff-1.4.4-556fe980.sh 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing Mojo Setup..............
Collecting info for this system...
Operating system: linux
CPU Arch: x86_64
trying mojosetup in bin/linux/x86_64

(process:9098): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:27:05.642: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.

(mojosetup:9098): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:27:05.673: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(mojosetup:9098): Gtk-WARNING **: 15:27:05.676: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",
Uninstalling prior version
Using script to fake tty
Script started, file is /dev/null
Hubstaff
Désinstallation en cours
Métadonnées
uninstall-Hubstaff.sh (progression totale : 0%)
Désinstallation en cours
Hubstaff
stop@2x.png (progression totale : 1%)
stop.png (progression totale : 2%)
stop-circle@2x.png (progression totale : 2%)
stop-circle.png (progression totale : 3%)
stop-circle-o@2x.png (progression totale : 3%)
stop-circle-o.png (progression totale : 4%)
square@2x.png (progression totale : 4%)
square.png (progression totale : 5%)
square-circle@2x.png (progression totale : 5%)
square-circle.png (progression totale : 6%)
search@2x.png (progression totale : 6%)
search.png (progression totale : 7%)
screen_7.png (progression totale : 7%)
screen_6.png (progression totale : 8%)
screen_5.png (progression totale : 9%)
screen_4.png (progression totale : 9%)
screen_3.png (progression totale : 10%)
screen_2.png (progression totale : 10%)
screen_1.png (progression totale : 11%)
repeat@2x.png (progression totale : 11%)
repeat.png (progression totale : 12%)
refresh@2x.png (progression totale : 12%)
refresh.png (progression totale : 13%)
plus@2x.png (progression totale : 13%)
plus.png (progression totale : 14%)
play@2x.png (progression totale : 14%)
play.png (progression totale : 15%)
play-circle@2x.png (progression totale : 15%)
play-circle.png (progression totale : 16%)
play-circle-o@2x.png (progression totale : 17%)
play-circle-o.png (progression totale : 17%)
onboarding.json (progression totale : 18%)
list@2x.png (progression totale : 18%)
list.png (progression totale : 19%)
list-ol@2x.png (progression totale : 19%)
list-ol.png (progression totale : 20%)
list-alt@2x.png (progression totale : 20%)
list-alt.png (progression totale : 21%)
info-circle@2x.png (progression totale : 21%)
info-circle.png (progression totale : 22%)
hubstaff-red.png (progression totale : 22%)
hubstaff-green.png (progression totale : 23%)
hubstaff-gray.png (progression totale : 23%)
hubstaff-color.png (progression totale : 24%)
hubstaff-black.png (progression totale : 25%)
apps (progression totale : 25%)
64x64 (progression totale : 26%)
hubstaff-red.png (progression totale : 26%)
hubstaff-green.png (progression totale : 27%)
hubstaff-gray.png (progression totale : 27%)
hubstaff-color.png (progression totale : 28%)
hubstaff-black.png (progression totale : 28%)
apps (progression totale : 29%)
512x512 (progression totale : 29%)
hubstaff-red.png (progression totale : 30%)
hubstaff-green.png (progression totale : 30%)
hubstaff-gray.png (progression totale : 31%)
hubstaff-color.png (progression totale : 32%)
hubstaff-black.png (progression totale : 32%)
apps (progression totale : 33%)
48x48 (progression totale : 33%)
hubstaff-red.png (progression totale : 34%)
hubstaff-green.png (progression totale : 34%)
hubstaff-gray.png (progression totale : 35%)
hubstaff-color.png (progression totale : 35%)
hubstaff-black.png (progression totale : 36%)
apps (progression totale : 36%)
32x32 (progression totale : 37%)
hubstaff-red.png (progression totale : 37%)
hubstaff-green.png (progression totale : 38%)
hubstaff-gray.png (progression totale : 38%)
hubstaff-color.png (progression totale : 39%)
hubstaff-black.png (progression totale : 40%)
apps (progression totale : 40%)
256x256 (progression totale : 41%)
hubstaff-red.png (progression totale : 41%)
hubstaff-green.png (progression totale : 42%)
hubstaff-gray.png (progression totale : 42%)
hubstaff-color.png (progression totale : 43%)
hubstaff-black.png (progression totale : 43%)
apps (progression totale : 44%)
24x24 (progression totale : 44%)
hubstaff-red.png (progression totale : 45%)
hubstaff-green.png (progression totale : 45%)
hubstaff-gray.png (progression totale : 46%)
hubstaff-color.png (progression totale : 46%)
hubstaff-black.png (progression totale : 47%)
apps (progression totale : 48%)
22x22 (progression totale : 48%)
hubstaff-red.png (progression totale : 49%)
hubstaff-green.png (progression totale : 49%)
hubstaff-gray.png (progression totale : 50%)
hubstaff-color.png (progression totale : 50%)
hubstaff-black.png (progression totale : 51%)
apps (progression totale : 51%)
16x16 (progression totale : 52%)
hubstaff-red.png (progression totale : 52%)
hubstaff-green.png (progression totale : 53%)
hubstaff-gray.png (progression totale : 53%)
hubstaff-color.png (progression totale : 54%)
hubstaff-black.png (progression totale : 55%)
apps (progression totale : 55%)
128x128 (progression totale : 56%)
hicolor (progression totale : 56%)
flag@2x.png (progression totale : 57%)
flag.png (progression totale : 57%)
flag-o@2x.png (progression totale : 58%)
flag-o.png (progression totale : 58%)
flag-checkered@2x.png (progression totale : 59%)
flag-checkered.png (progression totale : 59%)
finish-flag@2x.png (progression totale : 60%)
external-link@2x.png (progression totale : 60%)
external-link.png (progression totale : 61%)
expand@2x.png (progression totale : 61%)
expand.png (progression totale : 62%)
edit@2x.png (progression totale : 63%)
edit.png (progression totale : 63%)
edit-simple@2x.png (progression totale : 64%)
edit-simple.png (progression totale : 64%)
delete-simple@2x.png (progression totale : 65%)
delete-simple.png (progression totale : 65%)
compress@2x.png (progression totale : 66%)
compress.png (progression totale : 66%)
clock-o@2x.png (progression totale : 67%)
clock-o.png (progression totale : 67%)
circle@2x.png (progression totale : 68%)
circle.png (progression totale : 68%)
chevron-up@2x.png (progression totale : 69%)
chevron-up.png (progression totale : 69%)
chevron-right@2x.png (progression totale : 70%)
chevron-right.png (progression totale : 71%)
chevron-left@2x.png (progression totale : 71%)
chevron-left.png (progression totale : 72%)
chevron-down@2x.png (progression totale : 72%)
chevron-down.png (progression totale : 73%)
chevron-circle-right@2x.png (progression totale : 73%)
chevron-circle-right.png (progression totale : 74%)
check-square-o.png (progression totale : 74%)
caution@2x.png (progression totale : 75%)
caution.png (progression totale : 75%)
briefcase@2x.png (progression totale : 76%)
briefcase.png (progression totale : 76%)
bars@2x.png (progression totale : 77%)
bars.png (progression totale : 78%)
angle-double-right@2x.png (progression totale : 78%)
angle-double-right.png (progression totale : 79%)
angle-double-left@2x.png (progression totale : 79%)
angle-double-left.png (progression totale : 80%)
add-task@2x.png (progression totale : 80%)
add-task.png (progression totale : 81%)
Hubstaff.png (progression totale : 81%)
resources (progression totale : 82%)
Désinstallation en cours
x86_64
libXss.so.1 (progression totale : 82%)
private (progression totale : 83%)
lib64 (progression totale : 83%)
Désinstallation en cours
Hubstaff
README.linux (progression totale : 84%)
NOTICE (progression totale : 84%)
Licence_CeCILL-C_V1-en.txt (progression totale : 85%)
Désinstallation en cours
x86_64
HubstaffHelper.bin.x86_64 (progression totale : 86%)
HubstaffClient.bin.x86_64 (progression totale : 86%)
Désinstallation en cours
Hubstaff
COPYING.LIB-2.1 (progression totale : 87%)
COPYING-Pixman (progression totale : 87%)
COPYING-MPL-1.1 (progression totale : 88%)
Désinstallation en cours
Métadonnées
mojosetup_mainline.lua (progression totale : 88%)
mojosetup_init.lua (progression totale : 89%)
localization.lua (progression totale : 89%)
config.lua (progression totale : 90%)
app_localization.lua (progression totale : 90%)
scripts (progression totale : 91%)
mojosetup (progression totale : 91%)
xdg-open (progression totale : 92%)
xdg-desktop-menu (progression totale : 92%)
xdg-utils (progression totale : 93%)
splash.png (progression totale : 94%)
silentuninstall.sh (progression totale : 94%)
meta (progression totale : 95%)
Hubstaff.xml (progression totale : 95%)
Hubstaff.txt (progression totale : 96%)
Hubstaff.lua (progression totale : 96%)
manifest (progression totale : 97%)
hubstaff_com-Hubstaff_1.desktop (progression totale : 97%)
libmojosetupgui_ncurses.so (progression totale : 98%)
libmojosetupgui_gtkplus2.so (progression totale : 98%)
guis (progression totale : 99%)
.mojosetup (progression totale : 99%)
 (progression totale : 100%)
Script done, file is /dev/null
Uninstall complete: 0
astro@Wajih-HP:~/Téléchargements$ 2019-03-22 15:27:18.479990 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] ui_style_adwaita.cpp:437  DEfinineg adwaita
2019-03-22 15:27:18.480187 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] fltk.cpp:218  Define scheme: adwaita
2019-03-22 15:27:18.480243 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] fltk.cpp:230  Define scheme: adwaita first box: 64
2019-03-22 15:27:18.488927 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] fltk.cpp:218  Define scheme: cairo
2019-03-22 15:27:18.489042 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] fltk.cpp:230  Define scheme: cairo first box: 67
2019-03-22 15:27:18.489100 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] fltk_cairo.cpp:565  cairo_box_start : 67
2019-03-22 15:27:18.489287 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] Log.cpp:230  Echoing to stdout : 1
2019-03-22 15:27:18.489358 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] main.cpp:20   Hubstaff client started
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

The last part, i.e this one:

```
astro@Wajih-HP:~/Téléchargements$ 2019-03-22 15:27:18.479990 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] ui_style_adwaita.cpp:437  DEfinineg adwaita
2019-03-22 15:27:18.480187 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] fltk.cpp:218  Define scheme: adwaita
2019-03-22 15:27:18.480243 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] fltk.cpp:230  Define scheme: adwaita first box: 64
2019-03-22 15:27:18.488927 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] fltk.cpp:218  Define scheme: cairo
2019-03-22 15:27:18.489042 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] fltk.cpp:230  Define scheme: cairo first box: 67
2019-03-22 15:27:18.489100 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] fltk_cairo.cpp:565  cairo_box_start : 67
2019-03-22 15:27:18.489287 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] Log.cpp:230  Echoing to stdout : 1
2019-03-22 15:27:18.489358 [DEBUG] [0x2214de0] main.cpp:20   Hubstaff client started
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

comes back when I launch the created executable `./HubstaffClient.bin.x86_64` and nothing happens.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems to be telling you that you don't have a valid `locale` defined. Read `man locale`.

Comment: Yes I thought this too. I googled the error messages and tried some suggested solutions, but nothing has changed. I don't really know what to do.

Comment: This question is off topic as non-reproducible because it has been abandoned by the author.